# Как сделать редирект URL только в нижнем регистре на сайте на WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Мне необходимо 
https://mapser.com/map-SERVICES/ -все URL такого вида сделать таким:
https://mapser.com/map-services/ 
Сайт на WP. Каким образом это лучше сделать? 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать на стороне PHP:

```
if ( preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) {
    header( 'Location: ' . strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ),true, 301 );
}
```